# Mass Delete "Unspecified" Contacts in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, mobilepush, contactbuilder

Hi Experts,

Is there a way to get "unspecified" contacts in Marketing Cloud - e.g. orphaned contact from setContactKey in mobilePush - in order to mass delete them from Automation Studio?

I tried to get contacts by SQL Query from _PushAddress, but it returns active contacts only from mobilePush.

Thanks for your help! :)

edit : I tried to create List from mobilePush -> Manage button -> go to List tab -> create List , and shown like this:

[image]

Comment: This last screen shows you are configuring the filter incorrectly. You can't use the 'is equal to` option from the dropdown - the correct option is 'is null'. The difference is like a man having no name and a man named 'null' - you need the former. Null means there's absolutely no value associated with the column/field. Typing in 'null' as you do here would try to find customers that have that value as their DeviceID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this document:

[Permanently remove Contacts or Subscribers and associated data from Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313920&type=1&mode=1).

It includes a section about contacts "orphaned" by MobilePush:

> 1. In MobileConnect or MobilePush, create a filtered mobile list that meets 4 conditions:
>
>    Contact Key is not null AND Email Address is null AND Mobile Number
>      is null AND **Device ID is null** ​AND Address ID is null

---

Update based on the comments below:

- @EazyE is right with pointing out you're choosing the wrong option for the filtered list - it should not be `Device ID equal (=) null`, but `Device ID is null` (see the screen below).
- I tried to recreate what you were doing and noticed that when you start to create a filtered list in Mobile Push, the `Starting Population` is not selected by default (it's in top left location just below the *Create Filtered List* title), so you need to click `Edit` and select `All Contacts`
- I'm not sure on what business unit level you should be running this filtered list, but Mobile Push data should be business unit specific, so I would rather do the filtered list in the BU where you have the app. As always double checking is recommended before any deletion, so you could do this on the child BU and the master BU level to compare the results.

Creating Filtered Lists in Mobile Push:
[image]

List configuration
[image]

Comment: Hi Rafal, thank you for your reply! I have checked the link you provide before and tried to create a new List in mobilePush from "Manage" button, and when I save with filter: DeviceID is equal to null, showing List Count is 0.. When there're many orphaned records. Is it because I create the list from mobilePush, not mobileConnect?

Comment: @LyonStark, have you selected "All Contacts" as the base of your filter? It shouldn't really matter if you do it MobilePush, I guess.

Comment: Are you doing deviceid equal to null. Or deviceid is null? @LyonStark

Comment: Also, it is imperative that this query is run at the appropriate level within the organization or VALID contacts will be included in your delete.

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak is there "All Contacts" selection? Because I only click on "Manage" button, go to List tab, and directly create the List with DeviceID - is equal to - null..  I chose "is equal to" in the Filters. It's only displaying active records so far..

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak  forgot to mention that I am using child BU for this to get all inactive records, then plan to mass delete data from DE in parent BU.

Comment: @LyonStark, I updated my answer to give more info. EazyE pointed something very important here

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak thank you for the detail! I am just curious on how to get to that specific page from mobilePush? I tried to use mobileConnect it's the same as yours but for mobilePush I got the display as I add in the question section.. thanks a lot!

Comment: @LyonStark I'm really not able o get to a screen that looks like yours. In my case I clicked `Manage` in Mobile Push, there I went into the `Lists` tab and selected `Using a Filter` from a blue dropdown' - see the updated answer.

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak then I'll just create it from mobileConnect instead, with the similar layout as yours :) thanks a lot Rafal!